# How to check table exist or not exist

Tags: sql, database, vb6

How to check table is there or not?

Using VB 6.0

```
cmd.CommandText = "drop table t1"
cmd.Execute
```

Above code is working fine, but if table is not exist then it showing “table does not exit”

How to check table exist or table not exist?

Need VB CODE help?

Comment: I see that you are new and noticed that you haven't marked any of your questions with an answer. Don't forget to do this because not only does it get the answerer reputation (points), but it also marks it as the answer for others who might be searching for the same answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Jet MDB (and perhaps generically for many OLEDB Providers) you can use an approach like:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim cnDB As ADODB.Connection

    Set cnDB = New ADODB.Connection
    cnDB.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
            & "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Data Source='sample.mdb'"

    'Check presence of table --------------
    Dim rsSchema As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rsSchema = _
        cnDB.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
                        Array(Empty, Empty, "t1", Empty))
    If rsSchema.BOF And rsSchema.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Table does not exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "Table exists"
    End If
    rsSchema.Close
    Set rsSchema = Nothing
    '--------------------------------------

    cnDB.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to drop the table without throwing an error message, you can use the following SQL if you're using MySQL.

```
DROP TABLE t1 IF EXISTS
```

Other databases have a similar feature, but the syntax is different. To do the same in MSSQL:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't1') DROP TABLE t1;
```

Although that looks very ugly.. there must be a better syntax to get the same result.

Comment: I'd forgotten about INFORMATION_SCHEMA - I always always seem to forget that it exists - despite seeming to spend most of my Sql time using MySql of late! Good call :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off checking for existence of the table concerned, rather than trying to drop it.

The SQL syntax is dependent on the database server/engine you're using, but for Sql Server you could use something like:

Sql Server 2000:

```
SELECT 1 as Exists FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 't1'
```

Sql Server 2005/2008:

```
SELECT 1 as Exists FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 't1'
```

You can then use VB like:

```
Dim rs as Recordset
Dim iExists as Integer

rs = cmd.Execute
On Error Goto DoesNotExist
rs.MoveFirst
iExists = CInt(rs!Exists)
DoesNotExist:
If iExists = 1 Then
 ' Put code here for if the table exists
Else
 ' Put code here for if the table does not exist
End If
```

**Note**: This code needs tidying up and "productionising" (i.e. I haven't actually tested that it works as I don't have VB6 on this machine)